# Need help updating Lua code in Visual Studio 2017 C++ code

Tags: c++, lua, visual-studio-2017

I have this code that used to work in 2005 but it seems that Lua has changed and I admit I'm stumped.

```
bool SLua::getValue (const char *table, const char *key, int  *result){

lua_getglobal (state_, table);
lua_pushstring (state_, key);
lua_gettable (state_, -2); 

*result = lua_tonumber (state_, -1);
lua_pop (state_, 2);

return true; }
```

My compiled app crashes every time on lua_gettable (state_, -2);
Is this due to changes in Lua? I already had to swap lua_open() elsewhere with luaL_newstate().

Thanks for any help

Comment: This seems perfectly ok. Perhaps `lua_getglobal` failed?

Comment: Using F10 and F11 to move forward, the debugger doesn't seem to mind anything in lua_getglobal. It's only when I reach lua_gettable (state_, -2); that it exits with "The program '[12308] src.exe' has exited with code 3 (0x3)." There is no debugging information, even though I compiled and linked lua3.5.4.dll with /DEBUG:FULL and /PDB:FILENAME. It just exits. It's also not possible to step into lua_gettable for some reason.

Comment: I meant, did `lua_getglobal` leave nil on the Lua stack?

Comment: I'm not succeeding in getting the stack value during debug. Used lua_stacktrace() and still nothing.

Comment: Add  `assert(lua_istable(state,-1));` after `lua_getglobal`.

Comment: Hello again and thank you for offering help. When debugging, an exception is thrown at the line you suggested. I have included assert.h. It seems the value of "state" is now {...}.

Comment: It is unfortunate. I was not the one who added Lua to the code in the past. Unsure if this makes a difference, original code contained lua_open(), which would not compile now. I had to change the function to luaL_newstate()

Comment: Can you just try with the version of Lua that you used in 2005? (I'm guessing 5.0.)